# Serve static index.html and API on same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node/Express as an API proxy server and want to know if it's possible to render HTML (index.html) page for all GET routes *as well as* expose API endpoints on the same port. I'm using client side routing (react-router).

For example:

```
// Always return the main index.html, so react-router render the route in the client
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const html = renderHTML(req, res);
  res.send(html)
});

// Expose API
app.all('/api/*', (req, res, next) => {
    proxyRequest(...)
});
```

The problem is that doing when doing a GET request, the first `app.get()` catches it (for example: `fetch('/api/accounts')`).

I need to be able to make any request to any API endpoint route (besides `/`) and have the client send any method (GET, PUT, POST...).

Can I serve `index.html` to all client routes *and* have GET endpoints on the same port? Can I serve html to all routes *except* ones prefixed with `/api/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expose your endpoints first and then serve your html, it should do the job.

```
// Expose API
api.all('/api/*', cb);

// Serve HTML 
api.get('*', cb);
```

Comment: Excuse me, but what is `cb` ?

Comment: callback / handler function

Answer (score 1):

Make a directory called `public`.

Put your `HTML` and supporting files in it.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

//Your API routes here
```

The `express.static` will serve the static HTML files and then you can add your route statements. This will work on the same port.

Comment: How does `express.static` serve an API?

Comment: No, `express.static` wont serve API. Your existing statements will do it. This will serve the index.html on `/` parth

Comment: It seems like you might not fully understand my problem. It's a routing problem, not a static file serving one.

Comment: From what I read, you want to serve HTML files and have APIs on the same port. This will do it.